# Taylor Series of $ \frac{1}{1-x^2} $ about x=2

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to form a taylor series of the following:

$ \frac{1}{1-x^2} $ about $x=2$

I tried factoring the equation such that it becomes the following:

$ \frac{1}{{(1+x)}{(1-x)}} $

I tried to substitute $ x = h + 2 $ into the equation and obtained the following after using partial fractions to decompose the result:

$ \frac{1}{2(h+3)} - \frac{1}{2(h+1)} $

I do not know how to proceed from here.

I know I can just compute all the derivatives of the expression and evaluate them. But this would be non-trivial. Could someone please advise me on how I could solve this question?

Comment: Use partial-fraction decomposition on $\frac{1}{{(1+x)}{(1-x)}}$

Comment: I'm confused. Are you claiming that $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)}$?

Comment: @wckronholm didnt even recognize that mistake. Time to sleep i guess.

Comment: The OP did the same. I thought maybe the function under discussion might have been $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ instead and that's where the typo was.

Comment: @wckronholm So sorry. You are right. I typed it wrongly. Corrected the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
{1 \over 1 - x^{2}}&=\half\,{1 \over 1 - x} + \half\,{1 \over 1 + x}
=-\,\half\,{1 \over 1 + \pars{x - 2}} + {1 \over 6}\,{1 \over 1 + \pars{x - 2}/3}
\\[3mm]&=-\half\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{x - 2}^{n}
+ {1 \over 6}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\pars{x - 2 \over 3}^{n}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
\bracks{-\,\half + {1 \over 6}\,\pars{1 \over 3}^{n}}\pars{x - 2}^{n}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> {1 \over 1 - x^{2}}
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
> \half\,\pars{{1 \over 3^{n + 1}} - 1}\pars{x - 2}^{n}}\,,\qquad
> \color{#000}{\large\verts{x - 2} < 1}
> $$

Comment: How did you get 1/6 in your third expression?

Comment: @LanceHAOH $\displaystyle{\large{1 \over 2}\,{1 \over 1 + x} = {1 \over 2}\,{1 \over 3 + \left(x - 2\right)}= {1 \over 2}\,{1 \over 3\left[1 + \left(x - 2\right)/3\right]}= {1 \over 2\times 3}\,{1 \over 1 + \left(x - 2\right)/3}= {1 \over 6}\,{1 \over 1 + \left(x - 2\right)/3}}$

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks!

Comment: @LanceHAOH You're welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $1 + x^2 = (x - 2)^2 + 4(x - 2) + 5 $

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\frac{1}{1 - x^2} = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \cdots = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^{2k}$$
provided $|x| < 1$. In general, however,
$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{1}{1 - a} + \frac{x - a}{(1 - a)^2} + \frac{(x - a)^2}{(1 - a)^3} + \cdots \quad \text{if} \quad |x - a| < 1.$$
Now, simply replace $x$ with $x^2$ and set $a = 2$.
The equality above follows from the formula
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x - a)^3 + \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $x = (x-2) + 2$, then $x^2 = [(x-2) + 2]^2 = (x-2)^2 + 4(x-2) + 4$ so
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - x^2} &= \frac{1}{1 - [(x-2)^2 + 4(x-2) + 4]} = \frac{1}{-(x-2)^2 -4(x-2)-3}\\
&= -\frac{1}{[(x-2) + 3][(x-2) + 1]} \, .
\end{align*}
Now use partial fractions to finish it off.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a function that has been expanded in a power series about the point $x = x_{0}$

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (x - x_{0})^{n}
\end{equation}

and if the radius of convergence of this series is non-zero, then we can generate a power series expansion about a new point $x = x_{1}$ if this point is in the radius of convergence of the original power series. The new series is

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{k} (x - x_{1})^{k}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b_{k} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}
\begin{pmatrix}
n+k \\
k
\end{pmatrix}
a_{n+k} (x_{1} - x_{0})^{n}
\end{equation}

It is interesting that there exists a procedure to do this even if it is not practical to do so without a computer.